# How do I programmatically create Excel row groups with the +/- box at the top of the group, not bottom

Tags: excel

I am creating an Excel sheet programmatically.  I like to show group totals above each group, and for this to look best the +/- sign that opens and closes the rows should be at the top, where the total row is.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

TIA,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Put the formulas in the row, then group the rows below with the option - Data->Group and Outline -> Group.

Hope this helps..